# how to make a pop up after reaching the end of a query

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to html, javascript and php and I'm making a Log in module, the rest of my codes are working fine but I can't let the user know that his combination is incorrect, I want to run the

```
echo "<script>window.alert('".$Incorrect."');</script>";
```

when the $verify reaches the end of the table and found no match for the ID and passwords what's wrong or what's missing?

here is the entire code... ( this is a .php file btw )

```
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $PassA = $_POST['passA'];
        $PassB = $_POST['passB'];
        $UserID = $_POST['ID'];
        $Checker = false;
        $Confirm = "Select * From Accountstbl";
        $Incorrect = "Error: Incorrect Account combination For admin " . $UserID . ".";

        $Run = @mysqli_query($connect,$Confirm);

    if($Run)
    {
            While($verify = $Run->fetch_assoc()){
                if ($verify['AdminID'] == $UserID && $verify['AdminKeyA'] == $PassA && $verify['AdminKeyB'] == $PassB){
                    echo "<script>window.alert('Log In Success!');</script>";
                    $Checker = true;
                    echo "<script>window.location.replace('TargetPage.html');</script>";
                    break;
                }
            }
    if ($Checker == false){
            echo "<script>window.alert(".$Incorrect.");</script>";
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why `if ($verify = null)` is sitting there?

Comment: thanks, I forgot to remove that from the question, I was testing different approaches to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the line:

```
echo "<script>window.alert(".$Incorrect.");</script>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<script>window.alert('".$Incorrect."');</script>";
```

because `$incorrect` is a string embed into javascript and must be written between quotes.